# How to set parameters for laravel 8 factory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-factory

In my Laravel 8  reading how factory works at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing
when I set params in factory call :

```
$ads = Ad::factory()->count(10)->create([
    'year'=> $year, 'month'=> $month
]);
```

I did not find how can I read this name param value in my factory database/factories/AdFactory.php :

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Config;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Ad;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use \Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Services\SlugService;

class AdFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Ad::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        $text= $this->faker->text;
        $slugValue = SlugService::createSlug(Ad::class, 'slug', $text);


        $startDate = new Carbon('first day of this month');
        return [
            'title' => $text,
            'ad_token' => $text,
            'slug' => $slugValue,
            'phone_display' => (rand(1, 3) == 1),
            'has_locations' => (rand(1, 4) == 1),
            'status' => 'A', // password
            'price' => mt_rand(10, 500),
            'ad_type' => (rand(1, 2) == 1 ? 'B' : 'S'),
            'expire_date' => $this->faker->dateTimeInInterval($startDate, '1 month', Config::get('app.timezone'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraphs(rand(1, 4), true),
            'creator_id' => rand(1, 5),
        ];
    }
}
```

In this case year and month are not fields for Ad model, but I need them to set value
for expire_date withing given month.

Which way is valid ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
Reading https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-states
I remade factory and I did not find how to get my additive parameters :

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Config;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Ad;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
//use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use \Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Services\SlugService;

class AdFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Ad::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        $text= $this->faker->text;
        $slugValue = SlugService::createSlug(Ad::class, 'slug', $text);

        \Log::info(  varDump($this, ' -1 $attributes::') );
        $startDate = new Carbon('first day of this month');
        return [
            'title' => $text,
            'ad_token' => $text,
            'slug' => $slugValue,
            'phone_display' => (rand(1, 3) == 1),
            'has_locations' => (rand(1, 4) == 1),
            'status' => 'A', // password
            'price' => mt_rand(10, 500),
            'ad_type' => (rand(1, 2) == 1 ? 'B' : 'S'),
            'expire_date' => $this->faker->dateTimeInInterval($startDate, '1 month', Config::get('app.timezone'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
//            'description' => $this->faker->paragraphs(rand(1, 4), true),
            'creator_id' => rand(1, 5),
        ];
    }

    public function expired()
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes, $var1=null, $var2=null) {

            // $var1and $var 2 are null and $attributes has no year/month parameters 
            \Log::info(  varDump($var1, ' -1 expired $var1::') );
            \Log::info(  varDump($var2, ' -1 expired $var2::') );
            \Log::info(  varDump($attributes, ' -1 expired $attributes::') );
            return [ // This changes applied. Just example
                'description' => 'suspended expired',
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

and I pass parameters in factory calling:

```
$ads = Ad::factory()->count(10)->expired($year, $month)->create([
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: I would not pass values that are not present on the model into the factory, what you can do instead is define a factory state instead of passing explicit dates, you could just have a `expired()` state that sets the `expired_at` date to something you consider to be expired, the second option would be to pass the full value that should be stored in `expire_date` column when you call the factory.

Comment: Thanks for your hint.

I did not catch what do you mean by “the second option ”?
Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK.

Comment: @mstdmstd [Remul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65770708/how-to-set-parameters-for-laravel-8-factory#comment116288223_65770708) means calculate the value for `expire_date` outside your factory call and pass that value into the `create` method. Using a `state` function on your `factory` would be the recommended method.

Comment: In this case I need instead of ->count(10) to write for($i=0; $i< 10;$i++) ? But in this case I can not use method faker->dateTimeInInterval...